# Why does a webapp hang on SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, x11, freeze

I have a piece of code that needs to run inside a Swing application as well as in a webapplication. But it should do slightly different things in each environment. Therefore we check [SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29)

After working fine for some time this suddenly stopped working. It just hangs on that call and never returns. Any idea why that might be?

We are on java 6, tomcat 7 on a linux box.

UPDATE:

We removed the call to isEventDispatchThread() so my immediate problem is solved, but I'm still interested in an answer why this is happening.

We debugged a little more, got a Thread dump and found the stuff below for one thread. 
It shows many threads are waiting on it. So that explains the hanging.

`java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit` seems to causing the lock since it is synchronized. So Yura was hinting in the right direction.

So the question remains: Why doesn't it complete or to turn the question around why does `sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:-1)` hang?

There is a X11 running on the machine ....

```
"http-bio-8081-exec-10@10344" daemon prio=5 tid=0x1ae nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-13@10809
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-12@10786
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-11@10343
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-9@10345
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-7@10346
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-6@10347
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-4@10349
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-3@10352
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-2@10353
  blocks http-bio-8081-exec-1@10354
   at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:-1)
   at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$100(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:52)
   at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:155)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
   at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:131)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Class.java:-1)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
   at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:68)
   - locked <0x2507> (a java.lang.Class)
   at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:89)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Class.java:-1)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
   at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:834)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
   at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
   - locked <0xf9d> (a java.lang.Class)
   at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1689)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:857)
   at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1339)
   at xxxxxxxxxA.setCurrentUser(xxxxxxxxxA.java:196)
   at xxxxxxxxxB.setCurrentUser(xxxxxxxxxB.java:41)
   at xxxxxxxxxC.UserThreadLocalHandler.afterCompletion(xxxxxxxxxC.java:96)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletion(DispatcherServlet.java:1108)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:830)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:58)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:162)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
   - locked <0x2a42> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You need to show some concise code samples in your post otherwise we will only be guessing.

Comment: Educated guessing would be fine to me. Since I have no idea what might be causing this behavior I have no idea what part of the code base might be helpful.

Comment: Try introducing a boolean variable isSwing and set it from outside of this code. like from ContextListener in web context and from main class in swing context.

Comment: Thanks, a good idea for a workaround. Although I'd still like to know why it hangs.

Comment: for why reason you testing for `isEventDispatchThread()`, that doesn't make me sence, hmmm only in the case that you needed to use `invokeAndWait` ....

Comment: We are migrating from a Swing application to a web application so there are some ... "interesting" findings in the code.

Comment: Any guidance in the X11 client log? Is [headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/) an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` invokes `Toolkit.getEventQueue()` method, which has following source:

```
/* Accessor method for use by AWT package routines. */
static EventQueue getEventQueue() {
    return getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueueImpl();
}
```

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit` is declared as `synchronized` method - maybe this is the case. Also, please refer to JavaDoc of this method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit%28%29

Hope this helps